# Can I Limit Publishing for a Role?

Tags: publishing, permissions

I created a role with very limited access for a user to be able to update content on our site with Sitecore 9.2.

How can that role/user be set so that the user is able to publish ONLY what the role has access to?

The site is run by admins so we do not use workflow.

TIA

Answer (score 4):

You can update the `Publishing.CheckSecurity` setting, this will ensure that only items that the user has read/write/delete access to will be published.

```xml
<!--
  PUBLISHING SECURITY
            Check security rights when publishing?
            When CheckSecurity=true, Read rights are required for all source items. When it is
            determined that an item should be updated or created in the target database,
            Write right is required on the source item. If it is determined that the item
            should be deleted from target database, Delete right is required on the target item.
            In summary, only the Read, Write and Delete rights are used. All other rights are ignored.
            Default value: false

-->
<setting name="Publishing.CheckSecurity" value="false"/>
```

I would highly recommend making use of Workflow though, to ensure only items of the correct state are ever published.

Comment: Agreed but can I add workflow to the role? Or just to the item?

Comment: You would add them to the templates of the items. If you have a common base template that all other inherit from, then it could be as simple as adding to that one. If all your other users are admin (which is usually a very bad idea), then they skip workflow anyway.

Comment: The role in question (in a different department and with a lower skill level) uses multiple templates and those templates are used by others with much higher understanding of Sitecore (the Admins), which is why I stand by adding to the role.